# Help me identifying this bonsai plant

Tags: identification, bonsai

Please help me identifying this bonsai plant. 
Also what can i do to grow it more quickly and create a better bonsai.
[image]

Comment: Looks like jade (Crassula ovata). I think leaves a little yellow like that are usually signs of overwatering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is some sort of jade or similar succulent. Not exactly a bonsai as they stay that size naturally, but it's still a beautiful example of a bonsai presentation for a jade.

Comment: I'm curious: why do you say this is not a bonsai? When I search jade bonsai on Google Images, I see similar looking plants.

Comment: Because bonsai are trees, they are not tree like.

Comment: So are all jades I see when I search "jade bonsai" not actually bonsai? Technically any bonsai doesn't meet the qualifications of a tree

Comment: In the classical sense they are not true bonsai